# Can we declare class as 'private' in java?

Tags: java, class, private-class

I know that Java doesnt allow a top level class to be private however is there any way that the private classes are allowed apart from top level class?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: I tried it for top level class but compiler error as - illegal modifier for the class.

Comment: So, other than top-level classes, what kind of classes are there? *(that was a hint question)*. Did you try making any of *them* private?

Comment: I just tried inner / nested class ...thanks for responding!

Answer (score 4):

You could use nested classes.

Link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: Thanks, I have gone through the link and understood that inner / nested class can be private.

Answer (score 0):

A class is a user-defined (custom) datatype and you can't declare a `class` in Java as `private`, but **if you do not want to expose a particular user-defined data type (class) outside of another `public` class**, then you can declare that as a nested/inner class (i.e., as a member of the `public` class). You can refer [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html) for details.